# Sending email based on template for each address in Excel List

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Trying to create VBA code that can be run through Outlook directly.

An .oft template has been created and saved to a local drive. It has the formatting and attachments needed.

I would like to send email based on this .oft template to a list of email addresses in an Excel file, where Column A is the Recipient Name and Column B is the email address.

I get

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

```vb
Sub SendEmailsFromExcelList()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Object
    Dim ExcelWorksheet As Object
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim RecipientColumn As Long
    Dim Subject As String
    Dim Body As String
    Dim TemplatePath As String

    TemplatePath = "C:\Users\jsmith\Documents\Project\Test.oft"

    Subject = "Test Invites"
    Body = "Hello, This is the email body."

    RecipientColumn = "2"

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplatePath)
    
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jsmith\Documents\Project\File.xlsx") 
    Set ExcelWorksheet = ExcelWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your worksheet name
    
    LastRow = ExcelWorksheet.Cells(ExcelWorksheet.Rows.Count, RecipientColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow 
        Recipient = ExcelWorksheet.Cells(i, RecipientColumn).Value
        OutlookMail.To = Recipient
        OutlookMail.Subject = Subject
        OutlookMail.HTMLBody = Body
        OutlookMail.Send
    Next i

    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set ExcelWorksheet = Nothing
    Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
LastRow = ExcelWorksheet.Cells(ExcelWorksheet.Rows.Count, RecipientColumn).End(xlUp).Row
```

It looks like all my objects have been defined.

Comment: `RecipientColumn = 2` and not `RecipientColumn = "2"`  The `Cells()` method accepts either two numeric arguments (row number, column number), or a row number and a string corresponding to a column label ("A", "B", etc)  `"2"` is a string but not a valid column label.

Comment: Hi Tim, I modified it to remove the "" and just show `RecipientColumn = 2` but it still doesn't seem to be working for me. Should I use `RecipientColumn = B` instead?

Answer (score 1):

If the code is run with Outlook. You need add a line to define xlUp as a const (or variable)

```
    Const xlUp = -4162
    LastRow = ExcelWorksheet.Cells(ExcelWorksheet.Rows.Count, RecipientColumn).End(xlUp).Row
```

OR

- Add reference of Excel lib
- VBE Tools > References > Micorsoft Excel x.0 Object Library

---

- `CreateItemFromTemplate` should be inside `For` loop.

```vb
    For i = 2 To LastRow 
        Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplatePath) ' **
        Recipient = ExcelWorksheet.Cells(i, RecipientColumn).Value
        OutlookMail.To = Recipient
        OutlookMail.Subject = Subject
        OutlookMail.HTMLBody = Body
        OutlookMail.Send
    Next i
```

---

- Although `RecipientColumn` gets the value as `Long` type with VBA conversion. But you shouldn't rely on it. It should be `RecipientColumn = 2`.

```vb
Dim RecipientColumn As Long
RecipientColumn = "2"
```

- Please include `Option Explicit` to avoid some coding mistaken.

Comment: Thank you - now I am getting a different error message on row:         OutlookMail.To = Recipient -- Which says the item has been moved or deleted? Should I take away this line?

Comment: What's the error number and text?

Comment: It is Run-time error '-2147221238 (8004010a)': The item has been moved or deleted. I am getting an email sent to the first recipient on my list, but it seems to stop there, as though it's not looping.

Comment: `CreateItemFromTemplate` should be inside `For` loop. Please see my revised answer.